# Why is my view slow when I have indexed the columns?

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, view

In SQL Server I have put a clustered index on a view to **eliminate** the **inefficiency** of a **join using LIKE** statements:

```
   CREATE VIEW KeywordCount WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
    SELECT 
        K.ID AS KeywordID
        ,COUNT_BIG(*) AS KeywordCount
    FROM dbo.Grants G
    INNER JOIN dbo.GrantStatuses GS2 ON GS2.ID = G.StatusID AND GS2.Status NOT IN ('Pre-Submission', 'Awaiting Signatory Approval', 'Modifying', 'Closed')
    INNER JOIN dbo.Keywords K
        ON G.Keywords LIKE '%' + K.Word + '%'                                           --It's one of the grant's keywords
        OR G.Title LIKE '%' + K.Word + '%'                                              --Word appears in the title
        OR Replace(G.Title, '-', ' ') LIKE '%' + Replace(K.Word, '-', ' ') + '%'        --Word with hyphens replaced appears in the title
        OR G.Synopsis LIKE '%' + K.Word  + '%'                                          --Word appears in the Synopsis
        OR Replace(G.Synopsis, '-', ' ') LIKE '%' + Replace(K.Word, '-', ' ')+ '%'      --Word with hyphens replaced appears in the synopsis
    GROUP BY K.ID
    GO

    CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_KeywordCount 
        ON dbo.KeywordCount (KeywordID)
    GO
```

Then I added another index on the KeywordCount column:

```
    CREATE INDEX IX_KeywordCount_Count 
        ON dbo.KeywordCount (KeywordCount)
    GO
```

So why does the following query take 7 minutes to run? Shouldn't the index give me much better performance?

```
    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM KeywordCount ORDER BY KeywordCount DESC
```

**EDIT**
Thanks everyone, but I know that **LIKE statements and REPLACE will make this view inefficient**. That's why I added the clustered index. I thought that putting a clustered index onto the view would materialize the data into a table so that the database **would not have to do the joins**. The query plan does say that it is doing the joins. Why is that?

Comment: What does the query plan say?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I see 5 different `JOIN` conditions on Keywords, which are all linked with `OR`.  

SQL Server is checking every row for every one of these criteria, you are doing multiple replaces in some of those criteria, and the `LIKE` comparison you are running can't make use of an index because you are using `%xxx%` so it can appear at any point in the field.

There are underlying issues with your query besides having an index on the view.  What fields are indexed on  your source tables?

Comment: LIKE and REPLACE are expensive. You would probably be better served with [a FREETEXT search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx), let the database engine look after the LIKEs

Comment: Surely, if I add a clustered index to the view, then the view is materialized into a table, and selecting should be unaffected by the fact I've used LIKE with wildcards and a REPLACE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution in this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM KeywordCount WITH (NOEXPAND) ORDER BY KeywordCount DESC
```

For some reason the query plan wasn't using the index, but I added the **WITH (NOEXPAND)** hint and my query ran instantly - many thanks to Quassnoi for pointing out the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that WITH (NOEXPAND) means that the view should only look at the indexes, and not the table data. That means if the indexes are not up to date the view will not be either.

Comment: What would cause the index to get out of date? Surely the SQL Server Database Engine automatically maintains indexes whenever insert, update, or delete operations are made to the underlying data?

Answer (score 0):

A `LIKE '%' + Replace(K.Word, '-', ' ') + '%'` (`%` wildcards at the beginning of the search terms) will **NEVER** be able to use any indices. If you use that kind of statement, don't be surprised you'll have full table scans all the time.

If you really need that kind of searching, you need to either be okay with the speed you're getting, or maybe investigate full-text searching.

The other option would be to change your LIKE statements to: `LIKE K.Word + '%'`

If you use the `%` wildcard only at the end, SQL Server stands a chance to actually use an index on `K.Word` and thus speed up the lookup.

Comment: I believe the @op is talking about an indexed view and an index on `COUNT_BIG`, not the indexes on the underlying tables.